# Unregister Azure Resource Provider Feature

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Unable to unregister resource provider feature.
Registered with below command.

```
Register-AzProviderFeature -FeatureName DisableNetworkWatcherAutocreation -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network
```

Now unable to Unregister. Is there any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once a feature is registered you cant unregister it. for this reason Microsoft tells you to have dev subscriptions where you can test new features without affecting production subscriptions.

Comment: Wonder why your answer was down voted! I checked and there's no API for unregistering a feature.

Comment: stack overflow :)

Comment: also can I Un-register the Microsoft.Network and then re-register it again

Comment: you can, but it wont remove the feature

Answer (score 1):

You can un-register resource provider feature using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/unregister).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ability to unregister Provider Features has been added since this question was originally answered.

The AzureRM Powershell cmdlets version 8.2.0 includes the `Unregister-AzProviderFeature` cmdlet ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/unregister-azproviderfeature)).  The cmdlet was [merged](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/pull/12273) approximately two years ago, so it's likely that it has been available for several releases--however a quick skim of the release notes didn't quickly identify exactly what version first supported it.